# Searchable String-Array, Android?

Tags: android, arrays, string

How can I search through an String-Array? I've got an dictionary app and the words are saved in a String-Array and it would be user-friendlier, if you could search for the word you want to look up, instead of looking its way to the word. Can somebody help?

Thanks.

Comment: so your current solution is to iterate through the array until you find a given word?

Comment: why not use a hashmap? they have great lookup time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.  Then you can see if the word is in your 'dictionary' by using the `contains` method, ex:

```
ArrayList <String> myDictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
myDictionary.add(new String("foo"));
myDictionary.add(new String("bar"));


...
// To check if the word exists in your dictionary.
if (myDictionary.contains(new String("word_to_look_up")))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are looking for- do you want to see if the word is in the array, or what is the goal? If you want the user to get to the word faster, changing the string-array will not help the UI jump to the right place.

If you want it to be like Google suggest you could take your array and make a tree data object, which each node representing a letter in a word. Then if the user types a, you go into that node and offer possible words.

Comment: Well you will need an EditText for user entry, and an OnTextChangeListener (or something like that) and a Tree data structure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Arrays.binarySearch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29) method to search an element from the sorted array.