# print directory like tree command

Tags: java, algorithm, printing, tree, directory

I have to print a directory tree.
I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

  File root = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\example");

  if (!root.isDirectory())
  {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid directory: " + root.getName());
  }

  int level = 0;
  System.out.println(renderFolder(root, level, new StringBuilder(), false));
}

private static StringBuilder renderFolder(File folder, int level, StringBuilder sb, boolean isLast)
{
  indent(sb, level, isLast).append(folder.getName()).append("\n");

  File[] objects = folder.listFiles();

  for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
  {
    boolean last = ((i + 1) == objects.length);

    if (objects[i].isDirectory())
    {
      renderFolder(objects[i], level + 1, sb, last);
    }
  }
  return sb;
}


private static StringBuilder indent(StringBuilder sb, int level, boolean isLast)
{

  for (int i = 1; i < level; i++)
  {
     sb.append("\u2502   ");
  }

  if (level > 0)
  {
    sb.append(isLast
      ? "\u2514\u2500\u2500"
      : "\u251c\u2500\u2500");
  }

  return sb;
}
```

with this output:

```
example
├──a
└──b
│   └──b1
│   │   ├──b11
│   │   │   └──b111
│   │   └──b12
│   │   │   ├──b121
│   │   │   └──b122
│   │   │   │   └──b1221
```

I didn't manage to remove the useless deep lines. How to do this?
Also my answer is: "How can I keep lines connected(as much as the cmd's tree command)?"

Comment: refer this link too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655085/print-directory-tree

Comment: Hi Rick, have you got a good answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.File;
public class FileAssert {

/**
 * Pretty print the directory tree and its file names.
 * 
 * @param folder
 *            must be a folder.
 * @return
 */
public static String printDirectoryTree(File folder) {
    if (!folder.isDirectory()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("folder is not a Directory");
    }
    int indent = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    printDirectoryTree(folder, indent, sb);
    return sb.toString();
}

private static void printDirectoryTree(File folder, int indent,
        StringBuilder sb) {
    if (!folder.isDirectory()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("folder is not a Directory");
    }
    sb.append(getIndentString(indent));
    sb.append("+--");
    sb.append(folder.getName());
    sb.append("/");
    sb.append("\n");
    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            printDirectoryTree(file, indent + 1, sb);
        } else {
            printFile(file, indent + 1, sb);
        }
    }

}

private static void printFile(File file, int indent, StringBuilder sb) {
    sb.append(getIndentString(indent));
    sb.append("+--");
    sb.append(file.getName());
    sb.append("\n");
}

private static String getIndentString(int indent) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
        sb.append("|  ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, I added another parameter into your methods called hierarchyTree to indicate if at a certain level, we should print | or empty space.

It is used as a stack to easily maintain the folder levels based on the recursion level.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final File folder = new File("example");
    final StringBuilder sb = renderFolder(folder);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}

private static StringBuilder renderFolder(File folder) {
    return renderFolder(folder, 0, new StringBuilder(), false, new ArrayList<>());
}

private static StringBuilder renderFolder(File folder, int level, StringBuilder sb, boolean isLast, List<Boolean> hierarchyTree) {
    indent(sb, level, isLast, hierarchyTree).append(folder.getName()).append("\n");

    File[] objects = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File current, String name) {
            return new File(current, name).isDirectory();
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        boolean last = ((i + 1) == objects.length);

        // this means if the current folder will still need to print subfolders at this level, if yes, then we need to continue print |
        hierarchyTree.add(i != objects.length - 1);
        renderFolder(objects[i], level + 1, sb, last, hierarchyTree);

        // pop the last value as we return from a lower level to a higher level
        hierarchyTree.remove(hierarchyTree.size() - 1);
    }
    return sb;
}


private static StringBuilder indent(StringBuilder sb, int level, boolean isLast, List<Boolean> hierarchyTree) {
    String indentContent = "\u2502   ";
    for (int i = 0; i < hierarchyTree.size() - 1; ++i) {
        // determines if we need to print | at this level to show the tree structure
        // i.e. if this folder has a sibling foler that is going to be printed later
        if (hierarchyTree.get(i)) {
            sb.append(indentContent);
        } else {
            sb.append("    "); // otherwise print empty space
        }
    }

    if (level > 0) {
        sb.append(isLast
                ? "\u2514\u2500\u2500"
                : "\u251c\u2500\u2500").append(" ");
    }

    return sb;
}
```

A sample result:

```
example
├── a
├── b
│   └── b1
│       ├── b11
│       │   └── b111
│       └── b12
│           ├── b121
│           └── b122
│               └── b1221
└── c
```

Comment: `level` argument is redundant, use `hierarchyTree.size()` instead

Comment: @Bon I dont understand what are u passing in renderFolder method? could you show the main method implementation as well? you do you call the renderfolder method

Answer (score 0):

You must keep the information whether an item is the last one in the folder for all parent levels. That is, you should make `isLast` an array.

For example, when you try to print the item `b111`, that list should be `[true, true, false, true]`. The first entries tell you whether or not to print a vertical line, the last entry tells you wheher to print a corner or a T-junction.