# Java after extracting zip with dependencies file cannot find excel files

Tags: java, maven, zip, pom.xml, aws-device-farm

I have to zip and upload my test automation file to Amazon WS devices farm. Amazon log gives me this error "no such a file or directory" when trying to find my excel files.

Symptoms are as below:

1) I can run my tests in local
2) I can read my datas from excel file in my local. 
3) I can run my test with hard coded datas on amazon device farm
**Problem :** 4) I can not run my test cases with datas from excel file
In my zip file excels are under test-classes file

[image]
**Details**

excel files in zip file under test-classes folder amazon trows below error 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/tmp/scratchmISeRm.scratch/test-package7yGtbu/Referenceapp-Appium-Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar!/Baggage.xlsx (No such file or directory

**zip.xml**

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
  <id>zip</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
      <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>*.jar</include>
        <include>*.xlsx</include>
        <include>*.properties</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
      <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>/dependency-jars/</include>
        <include>/test-classes/</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.amazon.aws.adf.referenceapp.appium.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Referenceapp-Appium-Test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ReferenceAppAppiumTests</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thy.agentwebsales</groupId>
      <artifactId>bookingws-client</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.11</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
      <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.16</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.16</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0-BETA7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>releases</id>
      <name>Archiva Managed Releases Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.thy.com/artifactory/libs-releases-local</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>Archiva Managed Releases Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.thy.com/artifactory/libs-snapshots-local</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/Users/puren/Documents/workspace/JetMobile_iOS_AWS_Demo_TESTNG/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>/Users/puren/Documents/workspace/JetMobile_iOS_AWS_Demo_TESTNG/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/Users/puren/Documents/workspace/JetMobile_iOS_AWS_Demo_TESTNG/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/Users/puren/Documents/workspace/JetMobile_iOS_AWS_Demo_TESTNG/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/Users/puren/Documents/workspace/JetMobile_iOS_AWS_Demo_TESTNG/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/Users/puren/Documents/workspace/JetMobile_iOS_AWS_Demo_TESTNG/etc</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/Users/puren/Documents/workspace/JetMobile_iOS_AWS_Demo_TESTNG/etc</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>/Users/puren/Documents/workspace/JetMobile_iOS_AWS_Demo_TESTNG/target</directory>
    <finalName>Referenceapp-Appium-Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/Users/puren/Documents/workspace/JetMobile_iOS_AWS_Demo_TESTNG/target/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>zip-with-dependencies</finalName>
              <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/Users/puren/Documents/workspace/JetMobile_iOS_AWS_Demo_TESTNG/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/Users/puren/Documents/workspace/JetMobile_iOS_AWS_Demo_TESTNG/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/Users/puren/Documents/workspace/JetMobile_iOS_AWS_Demo_TESTNG/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/Users/puren/Documents/workspace/JetMobile_iOS_AWS_Demo_TESTNG/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just zip it up with your tests in a separate resource directory and then reference it like this:

./dependency-resources/someExcelFile.xlsx

You could also print out the working directory using this java program I found so then we'll have a reference point.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33437515/4358385