# macOS App Invalid Signature

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store-connect

I uploaded a new binary of one of my macOS apps to iTunesConnect, but iTunes Connect is telling my that my app has an invalid signature.
It worked before in El Capitan, but I just recently upgraded to Sierra,
 so I think that might be part of the problem. I've looked at some of the other StackOverflow questions, but none of them fix my problem.
 iTunes Connect sent me an email telling me about the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.
 Here's what the email said:

> Invalid Signature - This error occurs when you have signed your app's installer incorrectly. There are two certs required for this process: the "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" cert and the "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" cert. When signing your package, you need to ensure that you are using the Installer cert to sign your package. Ensure that you are specifying this cert when submitting your app via the Xcode Organizer or when running productbuild from the command line.

How can I fix this?

EDIT: The more I look around in Xcode trying to figure out what the problem might be, the more I'm confused. In Keychains, I have the correct certificates (I've even got several duplicates of the same certificate) but iTunes Connect is still telling me Invalid Signature. I'm not sure what's wrong.

I really want to get this problem fixed, so if more information is needed about the problem I'll be happy to provide more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting and some ideas from my friend Thomas (thanks @TDM!) I finally figured out the solution! Here's what I did:

So first I went under Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Selected my account > View Details and under Signing Identities I made sure to create the 2 certificates that I needed. After I did that I thought I was done, but Apple rejected my app again and I got the same error.

In Keychains I noticed that I had 4 "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" certificates and 4 "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" certificates. My friend Thomas suggested I delete the duplicates. I had thought of that too. But I had those certificates there a while and they hadn't caused me any trouble, or at least not until I upgraded to macOS Sierra. But, I decided to try.

I deleted the 6 older certificates (3 of the "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" certificates and 3 of the "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" certificates) but kept the 2 two certificates that I had just recently created. I uploaded the project once again to iTunes Connect and this time it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the email carefully. There are two possibilities

1. You are missing  "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" certificate. Please check all certificates via Keychain [Access utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_(software)#Keychain_Access)
2. You signed your application incorrectly. You should go through [codesigning in-depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2206/_index.html). Please post your app bundle structure for detailed help

Comment: I checked Keychain, and the certificates are there. So it must be that my app is sign incorrectly, although I don't know why.

Comment: What's my app bundle structure?

Comment: @NathanaelCarper app bundle structure means your application directory structure something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655085/print-directory-tree)

Comment: @TDM There are lots of certificates. iOS Certificates. Mac Certificates. And there seems like a lot of duplicates too. I've got the 3rd Party Mac Developer Application and the 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer, so no problem there.

Comment: @NulledPointer OK, I'll try to get my app directory up soon.

Comment: @NulledPointer I'm sorry, but I'm still a little confused. But where can I find the app directory structure? And I'm still not exactly sure what it is.