# How to get folder and subfolders name using Java swing and export in txt

Tags: java, file, io

I have this path /user/shared/name/Documents.
Inside that Documents have sub folders and files.

By using Java swing, how to get all the subfolder names only in that given path?
then click the export button and generate the text file for the path values.

Example.txt :

```
path /Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/

Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099923
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099923/000_Fonts
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099923/000_Fonts/fancybox
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099923/010_Correspondence
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099923/010_Correspondence/smart
Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099924
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099924/000_Fonts
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099924/000_Fonts/fancybox
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099924/010_Correspondence
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099924/010_Correspondence/smart
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099924/010_Correspondence/smart/images
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099924/010_Correspondence/smart/js
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099924/010_Correspondence/smart/services
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099924/010_Correspondence/smart/styles
Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099925
Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099926/020_Supplied
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099925/020_Supplied/doc
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099925/020_Supplied/font
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099925/020_Supplied/makefont
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099925/020_Supplied/pdf-ok
----Directory:/Users/User1/Desktop/arc_testing 2/099925/020_Supplied/tutorial
```

Comment: *"By using Java swing,.."* What has Swing got to do with this? It needs the `java.io` package APIs or similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print directory tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655085/print-directory-tree)

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Java 8, take a look at useful method [Stream walk(Path start, FileVisitOption... options)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-)

> Returns a Stream that is lazily populated with Path by walking the file tree rooted at a given starting file. The file tree is traversed depth-first, the elements in the stream are Path objects that are obtained as if by resolving the relative path against start.

Also, refer to this question: [How do I iterate through the files in a directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/how-do-i-iterate-through-the-files-in-a-directory-in-java)

Oracle has nice tutorial on it: [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)

Here is an example of traversing file system:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FileTreeExample {

    private static final String START_PATH = "/home/xxx/dev/python";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Files.walk(Paths.get(START_PATH))
            .map(Path::toFile)
            .filter(File::isDirectory)
            .map(File::getAbsolutePath)
            .forEach(System.out::println); // or write it to file

    }

}
```

*Result:*

> /home/xxx/dev/python
>   /home/xxx/dev/python/mongo_tutorial
>   /home/xxx/dev/python/mongo_tutorial/mongo
>   /home/xxx/dev/python/mongo_tutorial/mongo/**pycache**
>   /home/xxx/dev/python/mongo_tutorial/.idea
>   /home/xxx/dev/python/mongo_tutorial/.idea/dictionaries
>   /home/xxx/dev/python/pyminds
>   /home/xxx/dev/python/pyminds/messages
>   /home/xxx/dev/python/pyminds/results
>   /home/xxx/dev/python/pyminds/.idea
>   /home/xxx/dev/python/pyminds/**pycache**
>   /home/xxx/dev/python/bforce
>   /home/xxx/dev/python/trash

Comment: Hi Andrii, its throws errors..i suspu ect because of the import. could you post the full script?

Comment: @VinothMohan noц it should compile and run successfully if you are using `JDK 1.8+`

Comment: I got the output as per above by using another method. But the things is did not showing proper tree format like folder and subfolders and so on. like i mention as per above Example.txt

Comment: @VinothMohan we are here not for coding. Why don't you try it by yourself ?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that this forum is not NOT for coding. But knowledge sharing it will very helpful. I am new to this Java swing and i am trying to solve this by learning Java by my self.