# Is it possible to read a file structure from text file and keep track of parent node and child nodes USING JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, file, spring-mvc

Consider there is a file with the name "test.txt" and it has below file structure (refer to the image attached) red indicates folders and blue indicates files. Now is it possible to write a code to identify parent nodes and child nodes and assign values to each node in a way that it specifies who is the parent?

My database structure: Here id is an auto_increment value, where the title can be a folder name or a file name (that is a parent and child node names), and parent_id is the foreign key that refers to the id.

```
CREATE TABLE category (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  parent_id int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES category (id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

[image: Content of the file]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You'll need to learn how to access your database with Java. This will involve the JDBC (Java DataBase Connector) which is the java.sql.* package. You'll have to get the appropriate drive for the mysql database.

Comment: ^ "drive" = "driver".

Answer (score 0):

Get the title (say dir) from Database using [JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) as suggested in above comments and then pick either of these options from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655085/print-directory-tree) SO thread and use it appropriately in your service/view.

Once you get the title, just to give a hint, this is all you need:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String maindirpath = "/your/main/dir/title";
    System.out.println("Printing files under : " + maindirpath);
    File maindir = new File(maindirpath);
    if (maindir.exists() && maindir.isDirectory()) {
        File arr[] = maindir.listFiles();
        RecursivePrint(arr, 0);
    }
}

static void RecursivePrint(File[] arr, int level) {
    for (File f : arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
            System.out.print("\t");
        if (f.isFile())
            System.out.println("|_ " + f.getName());
        else if (f.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("[" + f.getName() + "]");
            RecursivePrint(f.listFiles(), level + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Its a simple implementation. Hope you got the idea.

Comment: This code prints files in a given directory (or title according to you that is fetched from DB). But that's not what I was looking for. I have a text file with the above structure...and I want to read that structure (identify parent and corresponding child nodes) and insert that data into the database. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Okay in that case, replace system.out.println with your dbservice.save method. How about that? Apologies if I am still not able to understand. Hoping you got the idea now.

Comment: The screenshot I have attached is the content of a text file. I just have to read the red-colored text as folders/parent nodes and blue colored text as files/child nodes. The code you have written above reads files from a directory...   but in my case, there is only one text file with the text that looks like a file structure...

Comment: Share some lines from your "that" text file (as is). So that its easier for everyone in SO to understand to find out the starting point.