# Viewing Folder of local file system

Tags: jsp, servlets

We are developing a file sharing site,with concept of users and admins using servlet 2.5,jsp and jdbc. We have implemented the file upload/download part via servlet. A user should see his uploaded files and folders in the site. But we are stuck in implementing folder level view via servlet. We maintained a add_file db table in pl/sql and retrieved file details uploaded by particular user only. But, we have to show folders also,which we are unable to show. 
I came across an easy solution of changing web.xml of apache tomcat 6.0 , but it would enable every user to see inside every folder and files,it will not depend upon database.  But we have to show those on basis of databases only. Any way to achieve this ?

1. UploadedFileView.jsp

   -----------code goes here

   ```
   <c:forEach items="${files}" var="file">``
           <c:url value="/DownloadServlet" var="url">
               <c:param name="name" value="${file.name }" />
           </c:url>

           <a href="<c:out value="${url}"/>"><c:out value="${file.name}" />
           </a>


           <br>
       </c:forEach>
   ```

   ---

DownloadServlet.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String filename = null;
        filename = request.getParameter("name");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String filepath = null;
        if (session.getAttribute("deletedfiles") != null)
        {
            filepath = DeleteLocationBO.DELETE_DIRECTORY;


        }
        else
        {
            filepath = UploadLocationBO.UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;
            }
        response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
                + filename + "\"");

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath
                + filename);

        int i;
        while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(i);
        }
        fileInputStream.close();
        out.close();
    }
```

Error Stacktrace:(test is the foldername)

> D:\Users\projectname\uploads\test (Access is denied:Http Status 500)

```
    exception 
        SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet DownloadServlet threw exception
    java.io.FileNotFoundException:D:\Users\projectname\uploads\test (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.servlets.DownloadServlet.doGet(DownloadServlet.java:57)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What's your concrete problem and question?

Comment: Files present in "UploadLocationBO.UPLOAD_DIRECTORY" are accessible via UploadedFileView.jsp. But if there is any folder present in UPLOAD_DIRECTORY location, i can not browse  that folder. It is throwing error. I want to access any folder situated in UPLOAD_DIRECTORY and access the files inside that folder. But I dont want to modify the web.xml of apache tomcat and overriding defaultservlet config to show directory structure.

Comment: Then, show us the code you use to list the folders, and the exception stack trace you get. How could we help otherwise?

Comment: Added Code and exception stack trace in the first post itself

Comment: It seems you try to read a directory as if it was a regular file. A directory can't be read. All it has is a name/path. I don't really know what you want to achieve, but test if the file is a directory before trying to read it: `File.isDirectory()`.

Comment: My basic need is to have a directory structure/ listing files and directories by filter and extension.


what would be the next step ?

if(File.isDirectory())
{

//what will be the code to browse that folder contents and get file names from that folder?

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple algorithmic stuff, but here's an example to get you started:

```
public void displayFileTree(File rootDirectory) {
    displayFileTree(rootDirectory, "");
}

private void displayFileTree(File rootDirectory, String indent) {
    for (File file : rootDirectory.listFiles()) {
        System.out.println(indent + file.getName());
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            displayFileTree(file, indent + "    ");
        } 
    }
}
```

Run this code from a simple console program, then adapt it to your concrete web problem.

If you want a Java bean that you can use from your JSP, it will simply have the same structure as a file:

```
public class Node
    private boolean directory;
    private String name;
    private List<Node> children;

    // getters omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: I can get the folder name easily on console, but i am stuck on showing the folders in jsp page in clickable mode, i.e, whenever i will run the jsp page,it would show folders and if i click on that folder, i can iterate through files inside that folder.

Comment: After lots of searching and researching, found out the following..
I have to Load My data into an XML, whose structure  have to define according to UPLOADING location.
Next, you  I can use XSL to render the XML onto a jsp page.


I am novice in xml. How can I convert the sample code provided by you to a suitable xml file. As , files will be regularly added and deleted, xml file need to be created dynamically on each go.

Comment: @DeSmOnd: no, you don't have to do that. It seems you're completely lost and don't really understand how HTML, HTTP and JSPs work. Follow some introductory tutorial which shows how to generate a page with links from beans stored in request attributes by a servlet. Your question is much too confusing to be answered.

Comment: my basic question is like this . 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755495/data-structure-to-store-a-directory-structure

Comment: And this question has been answered. Also look at my edited answer.