# Using Java TreeModel

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, treemodel

I know that this question has been asked here: [Java tree data-structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure)

But what is the best practice in implementing a tree in Java? The second most voted answer in the question linked above mentions TreeModel, but in the comments someone says that it isn't good coding practice to do so. Does this hold any truth? (I don't understand swing vs non-swing) Is using TreeModel common practice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java tree data-structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure)

Comment: Swing is a user-interface toolkit, and TreeModel is part of that toolkit. Zero coupling to any single UI toolkit is more likely to result in portable code. A tree data structure is simple enough that there's no significant advantage to using Swing's.

Comment: Does it make a difference whether I had mentioned that post in the question?

Comment: Seemed like this question was already fully addressed by the prior question. But this does have a different focus, so I may have been mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment you refer to says:

> I would avoid using Swing libraries on non-Swing-related functions. This is bad coding practice. You never know how Swing implements their trees, what their dependencies are and how this could change in the future. Swing is not a utility library but a UI library.

In my experience, Swing is a sophisticated UI toolkit, but all of the [model classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html), like `TreeModel` or `TableModel` are tailored for the purpose of supporting a cross-plattform UI. Maybe the name *model* suggests that these encapsulate independent inner workings of those data structures - but the existence of classes like the `ButtonModel` tell me, that all these classes are more there for support of the MVC model.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html):

> Why then do models exist? The biggest reason is that they give you **flexibility in determining how data is stored and retrieved**. For example, if you're designing a spreadsheet application that displays data in a sparsely populated table, you can create your own table model that is optimized for such use.

Answer (score 1):

The TreeModel and TreeNode is for implementing the model of Swing's visual Tree component. You can see this on their packages `javax.swing.tree` for example. You should only use them for what they were designed (UI-related stuff, see Javadocs) and don't use them as a data structure. That is what this comment tells which you have mentioned. And this is absolutely correct.