# How to create own tree in java?

Tags: java, tree

I want to know how to create own tree in java, it consists of eight sub-nodes and in each sub-node it having many sub-nodes. How to create this. please help me. I am newer to java.

Comment: Just similar as the other languages.

Comment: pls give some examples and reference to create

Comment: [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure)

Comment: Google `Java Tree examples` and you will find this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html

Comment: what are you exactly trying to achieve is very unclear

Comment: [possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure)

Comment: off-topic because you are asking "do this for me"...

Answer (score 13):

You'll probably need to create some sort of Node class to represent the nodes in the tree:

```
public class Node
{
    private List<Node> children = null;
    private String value;

    public Node(String value)
    {
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void addChild(Node child)
    {
        children.add(child);
    }

}
```

Then to populate your tree:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Node root = new Node("root");
    root.addChild(new Node("child1"));
    root.addChild(new Node("child2")); //etc.
}
```

You'll have to modify this to suit your own purposes, this code is just to give you an idea of the structure.

Answer (score 2):

A good design will be : Create a class RootNode with array of eight references to another class FirstLevelChildNode which in turn has dynamic array (say ArrayList) of another class ChildNodes, with required operations in each class...

Comment: You really only need one type of node, since subtrees are trees themselves, and it'd get difficult to tell roots from first children recursively.

Comment: Yes I agree to that. We can have a constant integer that restricts the no of children a node can have instead of having a different class.