# How do I create a tree like structure in which there are different types of nodes and each node can have references to any of the nodes?

Tags: java, data-structures

Nodes are, for example, of type `A`, `B` and `C`.

Each of these nodes are different number of children. `A` can have 2 children, `B` can have 3 children and so on. Now, whether `A` will have a reference to `B` or `C` is not known a priori.

How do I do this for `n` nodes where each node is an object of a different class and can have a reference to any of the `n-1` nodes?

Comment: use a common interface for A, B and C?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Node class and pass the limit for the child nodes in the constructor.

```
class Node implements iNode
{
  private List<iNode> childNodes;
  private int maxChildren;
  ...

  public Node(int maxChildren)
  {
    this.maxChildren = maxChildren;
    this.childNodes = new ArrayList<iNode>();
  }

  public void addChildNode(iNode child) throws SomeCustomException
  {
    if (childNodes.size() < maxChildren) {
      childNodes.add(child);
    } else {
      throw new SomeCustomException();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Node` can have a reference to different types of nodes, and which node exactly is not known before the `Node` object has been created. That is my main concern!

Comment: Node was just a generic name I chose. If all the classes you want to use in the tree implements a shared interface then you can add them as children.