# A custom data structure in java

Tags: java, data-structures, customization

I have a Tree structure on my swing UI. Each object in the Tree represents a element in the network. The elements in the network have alarms raised on it. Alarms (one or more) are represented in the UI with a bell image besides the network element. I use a Cache (TreeMap) to store the network elements with the name of the network element as the KEY and Alarms as Value. However, traversing the TreeMap is pretty in-efficient. The names of the network element are Strings. I would like to store the elements in a parent-child relation (like the real UI) and the STRING names fail to do that.

I would like to create a custom data-structure which would emulate my UI hierarchy. I would think that customising linked list would do the job for me. Is there any tried and tested data-structure which I can use? Any other opinions highly appreciated.

Comment: How about a class `Node<T>` with members `T value` and `List<Node<T>> children`? Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3522454/1639625)

Comment: @tobias_k I was thinking on similar lines. The questions stems from the fact that this should be a every day scenario on UI applications. Isn't there something ready made (some library) which would help me , rather than I reinventing the wheel.

Comment: In this case, how about using Swing's [`TreeModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html)? Particularly if you need the tree only for the GUI anyway...

Comment: Also see [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)...

Comment: Isn't javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel meant to provide the background for the JTree? And a subclass of it can handle any additional gimmicks you might require.

Answer (score 0):

Use domain objects for your data structure ("model"), with classes like `Site`, `Host`, `Application`, `NetworkLink` etc. Then you can have methods like `clearAlarms()` and properties like `getState()` and `getName()`.

Comment: that is a good idea. But there are hundreds of unique elements in the network. Also, its a legacy application, so I am afraid I would be allowed to add so many classes now.

Comment: Well, I guess you cant introduce another generic data stucture either then. You might be able to sell a rewrite, just think what you can gain from using a data model. A middle ground between your own domain objects and generic data structures would be something like [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) which does come with DSL and tree views, graphical panes and schema workbench.