# Tree representation in java for minimax algorithm

Tags: java, tree, minimax, pacman

I want to implement the Minimax algorithm in java.
I couldnt find a good tree representation. Is there an existing one or should I make my own?

- by the way this is for the pacman game
  Thanks

Comment: Can you please show us your efforts? what have you done so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java tree data-structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need one.

The minimax algorithm is frequently illustrated with a tree.

However, that tree represents the steps taken by the algorithm to choose the best move. It is not a data structure held by the algorithm.

Instead, you'll use *iteration* and *recursion*. At each interior node of the tree, you'll iterate through the children, and use recursion on each child.

Comment: I understand how you don't need a tree only to compute the minimax value. But if you're to use it in a game (question states Pacman) you need to keep track of the movement. Can you do that without a tree?

Comment: Yes -- you can keep track of the current game state, regardless how it was reached -- and use minimax to find the single next move.