# Convert a collection of typed dependencies into a tree

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am struggling with a problem for a while. Suppose you have a collection of typed dependencies (from `edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TypedDependency`) and you want to convert them to a tree (from `edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree`).

For instance:

```
// Suppose you get the typed dependencies from a grammatical structure object
Collection<TypedDependency> atd = gs.allTypedDependencies(); 
Tree t = null;
```

Now, how could I transform the object `atd` into a tree (which could be stored in `t`)?

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Maybe post some code

Comment: I wrote a code example, hope it's enough :)

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure) could help you.

Comment: Nope, I need a specific answer about Stanford NLP Trees. Tnx for the comment anyway.

Comment: After a quick search you could look at how to use a [TreeFactory](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/TreeFactory.html)

Comment: Yes, I did that too, but couldn't get around with it. Again, I need a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

These are not equivalent types. Typed Dependencies define a dependency tree (`SemanticGraph`), whereas the `Tree` class represents a constituency tree. While there is actually code to produce a dependency tree from a constituency tree, there is nothing in CoreNLP that would do the reverse. As far as I know, this is actually a nontrivial task.

My recommendation is to run the `parse` annotator rather than the `depparse` annotator, and get a Tree that way (see `TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation`).

Comment: Actually I am trying to convert GrammaticalStructure to a Tree (stackoverflow.com/questions/32565312/…). So, I thought that exploiting the Typed Dependencies was a good start. However, I found out that it is possible to construct the tree from a string like this: `(ROOT (S (NP (NNP Arnold) (NNP Schwarzenegger)) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (DT a) (JJ famous) (NN actor)))))` for the sentence "Arnold Schwarzenegger is a famous actor". This is done with the static method `Tree.valueOf()`. However, I don't know how to get to that string? Any suggestions?

Comment: BTW, thanks a lot for your answer, you definitely helped me a little with this answer, +1!

Comment: To get a constituency tree (like `(ROOT (S (NP (NNP Arnold) (NNP Schwarzenegger)) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (DT a) (JJ famous) (NN actor)))))`) you need to run the constituency parser, rather than the dependency parser. `LexicalizedParser.parse()` is the concrete method that does this; but, I recommend going through the CoreNLP interface and calling the `parse` annotator.

Comment: Actually, I already have the `LexicalizedParser` but I desperately need the NN parser for my research (needs to translate the `GrammaticalStructure` into `Tree` so I could extend an already existing code), so I will have to find a way to do this. I looked at the `parse` annotator, but I cannot see anything helpful for this there. Tnx again for your constructive comments, and of course, in case you have some other suggestions - please let me know! Cheers!

Comment: If you have to convert from dependency trees, you might be interested in recent research on the topic (NAACL 2015): http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~nasmith/papers/kong+rush+smith.naacl15.pdf