# Tree structure where children have different parent

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I need a data structure that stores integers in such a way that each number is connected to the two (or more) adjacent ones immediately below itself, like

```
      1
     / \
    3   2
   / \ / \
  5   6   4
 / \ / \ / \
7   9   8  10
```

I am trying to implement this in java. I am new to data structure and i am able to implemnet tree  structure but finding it difficult to implement this in java.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The Java Collections class doesn't have a default `Tree` implementation, but you can easily create your own as was done in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure).

Comment: that's not a tree. well, unless the edges are directed from top to bottom. and even in that case it is not a tree : )

Answer (score 1):

you can store it in the form of variable length 2-D matrix.

```
1
3 2
5 6 4
7 9 8 10
```

for index `(i,j)` it's left child would be index `(i+1,j)` and right child index will be `(i+1,j+1)` provided `i+1` and `j+1` are within the range in case of 2 child. You can extend this for more child as well.

Comment: can you elaborate this little bit more   with some more example

Comment: @RanjeetSIngh can u give your expected structure for 3 child case?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a tree structure as follows

```
class Node
{
    Node mNodeLeftParent;
    Node mNodeRightParent;
    Node mNodeLeftChild;
    Node mNodeRightChild;
    int miValue;
}

class MyTree
{
    Node root;
}
```

Comment: I am also trying this way only my creating a node but while traversing through root and creating the child nodes but i am facing difficulty while putting tht common child to two different parent refernce.

Comment: put your add function in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As data structures go, your situation is not a *tree* but a *graph* (more general). The JDK does not have a `Graph` data type (nor a `Tree`, for that matter) so you have to look to something like [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/).

```
DirectedGraph<Integer, DefaultEdge> g = 
    SimpleDirectedGraph.<Integer, DefaultEdge> builder(DefaultEdge.class)
        .addEdgeChain(1, 3, 5, 7)
        .addEdgeChain(1, 3, 5, 9)
        .addEdgeChain(1, 3, 6, 9)
        .addEdgeChain(1, 3, 6, 8)
        .addEdgeChain(1, 2, 6, 9)
        .addEdgeChain(1, 2, 6, 8)
        .addEdgeChain(1, 2, 4, 8)
        .build();

// the edge chains are just to be exhaustive in all the paths
// but only one edge is added, for each pair, like the following
g.addVertex(10);
g.addEdge(8, 10);

Stream<Integer> parents = g.incomingEdgesOf(6).stream().map(g::getEdgeSource);
Stream<Integer> children = g.outgoingEdgesOf(6).stream().map(g::getEdgeTarget);

System.out.println(" parents of 6 = " + parents.collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println("children of 6 = " + children.collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

You can also used undirected graphs but then you would need to get all edges connecting 6 and check if 6 is the source or the target to get what you want.

There might be an overhead, for your scenario, because JGraphT is very generic. Still it's very convenient and, after the first tries with the API, simple to use.