# Java Heap Implementation

Tags: java, heap

You will implement a heap from the following interface:

```
public interface Heap<V extends Comparable<V>> {
  public void add(V value);
  public V[] toArray(V[] array);
  public V remove();
  public void fromArray(V[] array);
  public V[] getSortedContents(V[] array);
}
```

> However, the **Heap** should be implemented as a **Node Heap**, that
>   is, the internal implementation should be a tree instead of an array.
>   The **getSortedContents** method should, internally, transform the
>   heap into its array representation, and the perform **Heap-Sort** on
>   it, then return the array as the result.

This prompt is kinda confusing to me. My question is what exactly is this asking me to do? I am having trouble understanding the prompt.
Does it want me to just create 1 class called NodeHeap.java that implements Heap?

UPDATE: 
So would my NodeHeap class look something like this? or am I completely wrong

```
public class NodeHeap<V> implements Heap<V> {

@Override
public void add(V value) {


}

@Override
public V[] toArray(V[] array) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public V remove() {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void fromArray(V[] array) {


}

@Override
public V[] getSortedContents(V[] array) {

    return null;
}
```

}'

Answer (score 0):

The main concern of the question seems to be that the data is stored internally in a tree (and a [heap tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) I assume), instead of implemented [with an array/list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation).
In fact I take the Node Heap as "heap implemented by node", but it works ok as a class name too.

While you can implement it in one class, given the fact that Java only has one [tree model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html) in the Swing package, it is pretty common to [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure) your own tree, which certainly involves more classes (can be inner or anonymous).
The question doesn't seem to mind that.

UPDATE: The code looks like a good start, assuming you are not going to actually return null when you are done.