# How create Tree object with same map Object (Java)

Tags: java

Hello i have a new problem today i need to construct an object like that with this particular strucural (i have made changes):

```
{ 
 principalid:
 {
 id:1
  { 
  price1:20,
  price2:30,
  price3:30
  secondaryid:
  { 
  subId:1 
   {
   price1:60,
   price2:80,
   price3:120
    thirdid:
    { 
     subsubId:1 
     {
     price1:60,
     price2:80,
     price3:120
     }
     subsubId:2 {
     price1:60,
     price2:80,
     price3:120
     }
     }}}}
```

I have my java object named Price with getter and setter

```
public class Price {

private Double price1 = null;
private Double price2 = null;
private Double price3 = null;
}
```

To create the first level, i used to declare a new attribute in my Object something like :

```
    private final Map<String, Price> mapPrice = new HashMap<>();
```

Where String represents Id but i want use same for subid and subsubId

How can i do to organise my object with multiple sub level ?

Do you have any suggestion or any sample to implement this solutions ?

Thanks

Comment: @Lionel_B you shoudl take a look at the "composite" pattern, it seems to fit your needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java tree data-structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure)

Comment: Hello thanks for you answer, but in example in deal only with string , i need to use some object

Comment: As stated before, look at [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to see how to build this sub-composition. `Price -> Price -> Price -> ...`

Comment: Thanks but this is very abstract , do you have any sample ?

Comment: Sure ... [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern#Java)

Comment: Yes it's very useful but how can i get item by id ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your data seems to be json, so you might want to take a look at [JsonObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) and it's use.

And/or a look at [gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

[Mykong has a short guide](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/).

Comment: This is just a common notation to represent data structure. Nothing in the question show that this is actually the JSON notation.

Comment: I know how to convert to Json, it's just for represents my idea, i want to know the Java code structure