# Sort Paths in Java to a Hierarchy

Tags: java, path, hierarchy

I have a List of n Paths and i want to create a Hierarchy ( Tree structure with objects ) out of them.

E.g. 
Paths :

```
/src/main/java/tools/mockfile/generator/data/RecordPart.java
/src/main/java/tools/mockfile/generator/Analyzer.java
/src/main/java/tools/mockfile/test/Menu.java
...
```

small Hierarchy :

```
 mockfile
    ├── generator
    │   ├── data
    │   │   └── RecordPart.java
    │   └── Analyzer.java   
    └── test
        ├── Menu.java
        └── ...
```

Is there any Library or Method who could help me to sort the paths to a hierarchy ? 
Or is the only way to split the Strings and compare all Parts and build my own Hierarchy?

Comment: You mean print out the hierarchy? Or create some kind of tree structure with objects?

Comment: Jep i mean to create a kind of tree structure

Comment: Should be able to do this using the java.io.File class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis i dont have the files local, only a list with the Paths

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java tree data-structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a nested `Map` as a tree, mapping Strings to other nested Maps. You could define a helper class just to get the type information right:

```
class Tree extends HashMap<String, Tree> {}
Tree tree = new Tree();
```

This way, the tree already comes with all the useful functionality it needs. Then, just iterate the paths and their segments and use `computeIfAbsent` to create new branches as needed:

```
List<String> paths = Arrays.asList(
        "/src/main/java/tools/mockfile/generator/data/RecordPart.java",
        "/src/main/java/tools/mockfile/generator/Analyzer.java",
        "/src/main/java/tools/mockfile/test/Menu.java");

for (String path : paths) {
    Tree node = tree;
    for (String segment : path.split("/")) {
        node = node.computeIfAbsent(segment, s -> new Tree());
    }
}
```

Afterwards, the `tree` looks like this (indentation mine; note that the root is empty string):

```
 {={src={main={java={tools={mockfile={test={Menu.java={}},
                                      generator={data={RecordPart.java={}}, 
                                                 Analyzer.java={}}}}}}}}}
```

Alternatively, you could e.g. put `null` for files (leaves) instead of another empty `Tree`.

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to create and manipulate tree structure the ad hoc library is Jgrapht.