# alignment of trees in Java

Tags: java, tree, alignment

I'm looking for any implementation of a Tree data structure for Java and any implementation of alignment of trees.

Anyone knows what implementations exist or have any other idea to achieve this?

Comment: [Probably a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your efforts to help the community help you better. It would be helpful if you go through the [Question Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and frame your question in a better way to reflect the problem.

Comment: @StutiRastogi Just mark these types of questions as off-topic.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Yup, will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with binary tree. This is little complex if you have not tried this implementation earlier and if you are relatively new to Java.

You can start here:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-implement-binary-search-tree-in-java-example.html