# Tree data structure with java (Nodes)

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I would like to create a new Data Structure with Java using only arrays. It's a tree of Nodes and every Node has as parameters :

- **a parent (node)**
- **children (a Array of Nodes)**
- **a letter (Char)**
- **a number (int)**

Every Node has a method *setChild* for adding a new Child. I don't know how to code the constructor and the method setChild of this Class Node. I'm very confused with this Data Structure.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Show us what code you have written, and please ask a specific question about a problem you are having.

Comment: Maybe you should learn more Java before achieving this so

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: actually i don't know how to implement such a data structure.

Comment: I would highly suggest looking at MinHeap it does something similar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java tree data-structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure)