# How can following data stored in appropriate data structure?

Tags: java, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

I have the following input data which needs to be stored in the appropriate data structure.

```
Electronics
Electronics > Arcade Equipment
Electronics > Arcade Equipment > Basketball Arcade Games
Electronics > Arcade Equipment > Video Game Arcade Cabinets
Electronics > Audio
Electronics > Audio > Audio Accessories
Electronics > Audio > Audio Accessories > Audio & Video Receiver Accessories
Electronics > Audio > Audio Accessories > Headphone & Headset Accessories
Electronics > Audio > Audio Accessories > Headphone & Headset Accessories > Headphone Cushions & Tips
Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Activewear > Hunting Clothing > Hunting & Tactical Pants
Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Activewear > Martial Arts Shorts
Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Activewear > Motorcycle Protective Clothing
Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Baby & Toddler Clothing
Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Pet Grooming Supplies > Pet Nail Polish
Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Pet Grooming Supplies > Pet Nail Tools
Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Pet Grooming Supplies > Pet Shampoo & Conditioner
Arts & Entertainment > Hobbies & Creative Arts > Arts & Crafts > Art & Crafting Tools > Cutting Mats
Arts & Entertainment > Hobbies & Creative Arts > Arts & Crafts > Art & Crafting Tools > Frames, Hoops & Stretchers
Arts & Entertainment > Hobbies & Creative Arts > Arts & Crafts > Art & Crafting Tools > Glue Guns
Arts & Entertainment > Hobbies & Creative Arts > Arts & Crafts > Art & Crafting Tools > Light Boxes
```

Which should give following infomation.

```
'Animals & Pet Supplies': 3,
'Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies': 3,
'Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Pet Grooming Supplies': 3,
'Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Pet Grooming Supplies > Pet Nail Polish': 1,
'Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Pet Grooming Supplies > Pet Nail Tools': 1,
'Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Pet Grooming Supplies > Pet Shampoo & Conditioner': 1,
'Apparel & Accessories': 4,
'Apparel & Accessories > Clothing': 4,
'Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Activewear': 3,
'Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Activewear > Hunting Clothing': 1,
'Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Activewear > Hunting Clothing > Hunting & Tactical Pants': 1,
'Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Activewear > Martial Arts Shorts': 1,
'Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Activewear > Motorcycle Protective Clothing': 1,
'Apparel & Accessories > Clothing > Baby & Toddler Clothing': 1,
'Arts & Entertainment': 4,
'Arts & Entertainment > Hobbies & Creative Arts': 4,
'Arts & Entertainment > Hobbies & Creative Arts > Arts & Crafts': 4,
'Arts & Entertainment > Hobbies & Creative Arts > Arts & Crafts > Art & Crafting Tools': 4,
'Arts & Entertainment > Hobbies & Creative Arts > Arts & Crafts > Art & Crafting Tools > Cutting Mats': 1,
'Arts & Entertainment > Hobbies & Creative Arts > Arts & Crafts > Art & Crafting Tools > Frames, Hoops & Stretchers': 1,
'Arts & Entertainment > Hobbies & Creative Arts > Arts & Crafts > Art & Crafting Tools > Glue Guns': 1,
'Arts & Entertainment > Hobbies & Creative Arts > Arts & Crafts > Art & Crafting Tools > Light Boxes': 1,
'Electronics': 9,
'Electronics > Arcade Equipment': 3,
'Electronics > Arcade Equipment > Basketball Arcade Games': 1
```

I have implemented using python3 in following way which has time complexity of O(n) where n is number of lines in file. Is there other efficient solution to store above information.

```py
def get_data(file_path):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):     # check file exist or not
            raise FileNotFoundError
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('please provide valid file path')
        exit()
    inventory = {}
    with open(file=file_path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as file_descr:
        try:
            for line in file_descr:
                line = line.strip()
                llist = line.split('>')         # list of keys
                for i in range(1, len(llist) + 1):     # check entry of each possible key in inventory
                    key = ('>'.join(llist[:i])).strip()
                    if inventory.get(key):
                        inventory[key] += 1
                    else:
                        inventory[key] = 1
        except Exception as e:
            print('not able to read content', e)
            exit()
    return inventory
```

Comment: How large is `n`?

Comment: ```n``` can be up to 5000.

Comment: Then it does not matter. Any working algorithm will be fast enough.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "data structures efficient look-up", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create class for your model and do it with tree structure.

Comment: can you provide the code snap for better understanding in python or java?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure you can use this link to build your model and entity framework is great framework for you to use i assume.