# What is the best datastructure for hierarchical data representation in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, tree

I need to create a data structure in java which can represents hierarchy of data. Example use case is shown in the image below.

[an organization hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKocG.png)

In my case only the leaves level will have data, and the internal nodes should act like indexes. I should be able to get data from the data structure using multiple keys(Composite keys).

Is it okay to use nested maps, or should I implement an m way tree(B tree/B+ tree) for this use case.

Comment: You should implement proper classes, as the different hierarchy levels have a set type (university -> faculty -> field).

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure

Comment: Thanks for responding. In my usecase only the leaf level will have values, internal nodes should act like indexes.

Comment: https://www.lavivienpost.com/build-hierarchy-tree/

Answer (score 1):

If the structure of the nested data is constant you could use normal classes with properties.

If the structure is dynamic I would use `Map`s, the interface and ignore the implementation.

About using using a custom tree structure, if you can use classes, thats better. If you use `Map`s, I would start with a `HashMap` and if you find it to be a problem your can replace your `Map` to something else later.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you have to use Tree like data structure. Here is the sample code of that.

**High level code idea**

```
class Entity{  
    // declare you attributes and below two properties

    List<Entity> children;

    boolean isleafNode;// for parent node its 'false' and for leaf node it will 'true'

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can implement Trie for this use case. Iterate over composite key and return data if found.

class definition:

```
public class TrieNode {
    private HashMap<String, TrieNode> children;
    private Data data;
    private boolean isLeaf;

   // ...
}
```

find query will look like:

```
public Data find(List<String> compositeKey) {
    TrieNode current = root;
    for (String key: compositeKey) {
        TrieNode node = current.getChildren().get(key);
        if (node == null) {
            return null;
        }
        current = node;
    }
    if(current.isLeaf()) {
       return current.getData();
    } else {
       return null;
    }         
}
```

insert will look like:

```
public void insert(List<String> compositeKey, Data data) {
    TrieNode current = root;

    for (String key: compositeKey) {
        current = current.getChildren()
          .computeIfAbsent(key, c -> new TrieNode());
    }
    current.setLeaf(true);
    current.setData(data);
}
```