# Basic Binomial options pricing model

Tags: java, algorithm

I tried creating a Binomial options pricing model tree in java but can't come up with a way to make an inner tree.

[image: Picture of how it suppose to look like]

So far the code I have is this

```java
  double[][] Price = new double[4][4];

  for (int i = 0; i < Price.length; i++) {
     Price[0][i] = Math.pow(m.U(), i);
     Price[i][0] = Math.pow(m.D(), i);
     System.out.println("u^" + i + ":" + Price[0][i]);
     System.out.println("d^" + i + ":" + Price[i][0]);
  }
```

This only output up and down branches only but I want all the inner tree branches depending on the nodes there are.

Comment: Do your tree structure need to be a `double[][]`, or you can use another memory structure ?

Comment: I can use another memory structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is to use recursion on a custom tree structure.

The structure I'd use is one like the ones [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure), but as a binary tree (with only two children). Example :

```java
public class BinTree {
    private float data;
    private BinTree left; //left Sub-Tree
    private BinTree right; //right Sub-Tree

    /* creation of the tree */
    public Tree(float rootData) {
        data = rootData;
        /* left and right are NULL, which means that 
           there is no left child and no right child */
    }

    public addLeft(float data) {
        left = new BinTree(data);
        /* You can verify first if there's a child, 
           and maybe give an exception if there is */
    }
    public addRight(T data) {
        right = new BinTree(data);
        /* You can verify first if there's a child, 
           and maybe give an exception if there is */
    }

    /* methods like your algorithm */
    ...
}
```

*You can replace `float` by any type*

With this structure, recursion becomes quite easy.

And to deal with this problem recursively, you need to imagine this : you are at a node, what do you need to do on this node ? Do you need to apply something on the children ? If yes, how can you use the same function to have the expected output ?

From what I see of your picture, there is 3 cases :

**1 - The value of the current node is `So`**

Then, your child left should get the value `So * u` and your child right should get the value `So * d`.

**2 - The value of the current node is `So * nd`, for `n` an integer**

Then, your child left should get the value `So * (n-1)d` (and just `So` if `n = 1`) and your child right should get the value `So * (n+1)d`.

**3 - The value of the current node is `So * nu`, for `n` an integer**

Then, your child left should get the value `So * (n+1)u` and your child right should get the value `So * (n-1)u`.

So the implementation (of the method) should be like :

```java
    public myAlgo(float s /*So*/, T/*the type of your variable m*/ m, int height) {
        myAlgo_rec(s, m, height, 0);
    }

    private myAlgo_rec(float s, T m, int height, int occurU) {
        /* occurU is equivalent to n, and indicates if we use U or D depending on the sign */
        if (height == 0) return; // Stop condition

        if (occurU = 0) {
            left = new BinTree(s * m.U);
            right = new BinTree(s * m.D);
            myAlgo_rec(s, m, height-1, 1);
            myAlgo_rec(s, m, height-1, -1);

        } else if (occurU < 0) {
            left = new BinTree(s * Math.pow(m.U(), -occurU+1));
            right = new BinTree(s * Math.pow(m.U(), -occurU-1));
            myAlgo_rec(s, m, height-1, occurU+1);
            myAlgo_rec(s, m, height-1, occurU-1);

        } else /*occurU > 0*/ {
            left = new BinTree(s * Math.pow(m.D(), occurU+1));
            right = new BinTree(s * Math.pow(m.D(), occurU-1));
            myAlgo_rec(s, m, height-1, occurU+1);
            myAlgo_rec(s, m, height-1, occurU-1);
        }
    }
```

Here it is. Normally, I think that if you understood all I said, you should be able to implement it or use my code (and debug it).

Comment: What is "m" and "height" means?

Comment: "m" is the "m" in your code (when your write `Math.pow(m.U(), i);` for example). "height" is the height of your total tree (4 in the code you've given, and 5 in the picture)

Comment: But I just saw that the structure given by the picture is actually not a tree... so my solution doesn't work, or at least doesn't work properly