# How could i make a data structure like linked list, but each node holds N elements?

Tags: java, arrays, list, pointers

So I want to make a linked list type of structure in the sense that each "group" of N elements also holds either a NULL pointer or a pointer to the next group.

So for example, I read an integer of 4, i want then to create a structure which hold 4 integers plus a NULL pointer, and then later if I wish to create another group of 4 integers i can change the NULL pointer of the first group to point to the second group.

PS: i'd like to achieve this in Java

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/how-to-implement-a-tree-data-structure-in-java) should help.

Comment: Let each node hold an array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to add a group of N elements to a data structure, and then this group can reference another group of M elements, and so on.
You can use LinkedList of LinkedList.

```
    LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> outerList = new LinkedList<>();
    
    int input = 4;
    LinkedList<Integer> innerList = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) innerList.add(i);
    outerList.add(innerList);
    
    input = 3;
    innerList = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) innerList.add(i);
    outerList.add(innerList);

    
    LinkedList<Integer> myList = outerList.get(/*the index of the group you want*/);
    myList.get(/*the element you want from that group*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Linked list is a data-structure that consists of nodes. Each node has a data and a next. The next is another node (or `null` if you are at the end of the list). Since data can be anything, you can define a `List` of the type of your choice. Example:

```
List<int[]> myList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

and then you can define each element as an array of n elements. You can use other data types as well.