# Deleting MVC Components - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I have a Java Swing app that uses the MVC pattern to build windows.  Here's a simple overview of the setup: I have a parent window consisting of ParentWindowController, ParentWindowModel, ParentWindowView. This parent window creates a child window, which likewise consists of ChildWindowController, ChildWindowModel, ChildWindowView.

The ParentController creates the Child window by adding an actionListener to one of ParentWindowView's buttons, and also adds a listener for when the Child view closes:

```
private void buttonListener(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    ChildWindowModel cwm = new ChildWindowModel();
    ChildWindowView cwv = new ChildWindowView();
    this.childWindow = cwv; // stored for deleting the child if the parent is closed (doesn't seem to work right)
    new ChildWindowController(cwm, cwv, this); // uses 'this' because needs access to some parent state
    cwv.setLocationRelativeTo(this.view);
    cwv.addWindowListener(new childWindowOpenCloseListener(actionEvent));
}

static class childWindowOpenCloseListener extends WindowAdapter {
    private final ActionEvent actionEvent;

    public childWindowOpenCloseListener(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        this.actionEvent = actionEvent;
    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent evt) {
        ... // some logic for disabling the window open button
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
        ... // some logic for enabling the window open button
    }
}

...

ParentWindowController() {
    // this is where i add the button listener to open the child window
    this.view.addChildWindowButtonListener(this::buttonListener);
...
}
```

The ChildWindowController also adds some listeners to the ChildWindowView as well as to the ParentWindowView. I won't show them in code, since they are similar to the listener above - just imagine I call in the ChildWindowController:

```
public ChildWindowController(cwm, cwv, parent) {
    ...
    parent.view.addSomeButtonListener(anotherButtonListener);
    this.view.addWindowListener(anotherOpenCloseListener);
}
```

Ok, so the problem is, when I close the ChildWindowView (it's a JFrame), the ChildWindowController stays alive. In fact, so does the ChildWindowView. If I reopen it, the state is preserved, the constructor is not called again. How do I A) delete the ChildWindowView completely when the frame is closed and B) delete the ChildWindowController when the view is closed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My first thought is much of that should the domain of the controller - it should be monitoring the view contractual events and handling them.  Based on the available snippets, `buttonListener` should be creating a new instance of the model/view/controller each time, so, unless you're making some use of `static` I'm not sure how it's preserving the state between calls. `parent.view.addSomeButtonListener(anotherButtonListener);` seems like a code smell to me

Comment: You're using MVC like it's CVM.  Your application should have one and only one application model made up of one or more plain Java getter/setter classes.  The view is the entire Swing GUI, consisting of one `JFrame` and as many `JPanels` as necessary.  Each controller is a Swing `Action` or `Listener`.  You have as many controllers as you have `JButtons`.  Take a look at this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76740120/how-do-i-change-the-text-in-a-jtextarea-and-jcombobox/76742052#76742052) for a fuller explanation of Swing MVC.

Comment: @MadProgrammer So I save the ChildWindowView reference in that instance variable `this.childWindow`. I think maybe this keeps the view object from being garbage collected? Or could it be that the buttonListener is keeping it alive and needs to be removed/deregistered? The `parent.view.addSomeButtonListener(anotherButtonListener);` is needed because the child window needs to run some task but only when a certain button in the parent window has been pressed, call it `startTasks` button.

Comment: *"The parent.view.addSomeButtonListener(anotherButtonListener); is needed because the child window needs to run some task but only when a certain button in the parent window has been pressed"* - That's what an observer pattern is via and that should be executed via the controller, not the view.  Your child MVC should have little to no knowledge of it's caller, otherwise you've tightly coupled the code which is counter to what MVC is trying to do.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That's interesting, I did not know the difference. To provide more context though, this parent and child window I'm talking about are just one feature of a larger GUI application consisting of a main window, from which you open various other windows (including this). The codebase is quite gigantic, that's why I assume it was originally split up into this pattern, where each sub window uses MVC. In any case, I'm not sure this is relevant to my original question.